# websphere remote ejb call CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST LocateReply.UNKNOWN_OBJECT minor code: C01

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere

I have two local websphere 7 application servers (two profiles) on the same machine. Just a default installation with no custom configuration. One exposes a service deployed as an EJB3 session bean with ejb/edu/test/EjbFacade JNDI name.

I wrote a simple JUnit integration test which calls a method remotely:

```
@Test
public void testCall() throws Exception {
    Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
    props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2811");
    props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
    props.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass", "com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB");
    InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(props);

    Object obj = initialContext.lookup("cell/nodes/myNode03/servers/server1/ejb/edu/test/EjbFacade");
    EjbFacade facade = (EjbFacade) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(obj, EjbFacade.class);
    facade.doSomething();
}
```

**This works fine!**

Then I have a web application with an EJB reference:

ibm-web-bnd.xmi

```
  <ejbRefBindings xmi:id="EjbRefBinding_1386431681401" jndiName="ejb/edu/test/EjbFacade">
      <bindingEjbRef href="WEB-INF/web.xml#EjbRefBinding_EjbFacade"/>
  </ejbRefBindings>
```

web.xml

```
  <ejb-ref id="EjbRefBinding_EjbFacade">
      <ejb-ref-name>ejb/edu/test/EjbFacade</ejb-ref-name>
      <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
      <home/>
      <remote>edu.test.EjbFacade</remote>
  </ejb-ref>
```

And I am doing the same EJB call from a servlet using local JNDI name: **java:comp/env/ejb/edu/test/EjbFacade** mapped to **corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2811/cell/nodes/myNode03/servers/server1/ejb/edu/test/EjbFacade** in websphere admin console.

The call fails with exception:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: A communication failure
occurred while attempting to obtain an initial context with the provider URL: 
"corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2811/cell/nodes/myNode03/servers/server1/ejb/edu/test/EjbFacade". 
Make sure that any bootstrap address information in the URL is correct and that the target 
name server is running.  A bootstrap address with no port specification defaults to port 2809.
Possible causes other than an incorrect bootstrap address or unavailable name server 
include the network environment and workstation network configuration. 
[Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST: LocateRequest 6 received    
LocateReply.UNKNOWN_OBJECT  vmcid: IBM  minor code: C01  completed: No]
```

**What JNDI name should I configure in the WAS console? Why the same code is working under JUnit but fails from the servlet?**

Comment: Also checked websphere documentation: the error description is "Ensure that the remote object that is requested resides in the specified server and that the remote reference is up-to-date". Could anybody elaborate a bit what "the remote reference is up-to-date" means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the uniqueServerName option.  See the "Two servers with the same name running on the same host are being used to interoperate" section of the [Application access problems](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rtrb_namingprobs.html) topic in the InfoCenter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, managed to make it working.

The problem was that websphere installer created by default two servers with the same name: server1

- myNode01Cell/myNode01/server1
- myNode02Cell/myNode02/server1

and there is a [bug](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&context=SSEQTP&dc=DB520&dc=D600&dc=DB530&dc=D700&dc=DB500&dc=DB540&dc=DB510&dc=DB550&q1=%22objectName%22%20not%20found&uid=swg21201631&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en) in WAS that caused such a problem. Renaming one server fixed the ejb call.

Comment: I requested an update to this technote, and it now also mentions the uniqueServerName solution. Thanks for pointing out this omission.